# How to include two namespaces with same name in a?

Tags: .net, namespaces

I have two namespaces with same name. Can I refer both in same file?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Do you mean two classes with the same name? Having classes that belong to a single namespace spread over multiple assemblies should introduce no problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an alias.  See [How to: Use the Namespace Alias Qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)

Two relevant pats:

```
global::System.Console.WriteLine(number);
```

This will always work, even if you have other `System` or `Console` names.

```
using colAlias = System.Collections;
```

This lets you declare an alias for a given namespace.

Comment: Can u give me with an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
using MyNamespace1 = Namespace1.Test.ClassName;
using MyNamespace2 = Namespace2.Test.ClassName;
```